# PHP use variable defined outside of function

Tags: php

I have seen a lot of questions already asked about the use of variables in functions or outside functions, but somehow I can't make it work in my case.

I have a PHP-file that declares two variables, and then starts defining a function. I want to use the 2 variables and a couple of arguments that should be passed along to the function.

I saw the "use" command that is available on anonymous functions, but I don't think that is what I want as the function does multiple things, and not just return a value. How can I use the variables in my funtion without resorting to global?

For clarification, my code looks like this:

```
$var1 = 'variable 1';
$var2 = 'variable 2';

function MyFunction($arg1,$arg2,$arg3){
    // use $var1 and $var2 along with the 3 arguments supplied
}
```

Comment: _How can I use the variables in my funtion without resorting to global_? Why not?

Comment: Pass them as parameters.

Comment: Could you give an example @Barmar

Comment: `function MyFunction($arg1,$arg2,$arg3, $var1, $var2)` and then add them as additional arguments when calling the function.

Comment: If you don't want to access `$var` and `$var2` using `gloabl` keyword you have to pass to the function all elements which are need by the function to perform it task, which is reffered to as **dependency injection**